# Consider parameters vs Solve-for parameters in regression

Tags: regression, terminology, nonlinear-regression

Lite form:

I'm trying to find the correct terminology to use to separate between "consider" parameters (included in the regression model, but held fixed and not estimated) and "solve-for" parameters (estimated by the regression model) with respect to regression analysis, and any guidance on implementing it. I've been googling for an hour, but i can't find any solid references to what I'm referring to, nor any definitively better terminology for it.

Long form:

I'm working on code to perform a non-linear least squares regression on a data set, with SVD as the backbone solution. Any of the parameters i'm performing the regression for should be able to be set to one of three modes: Estimate (solve for), Consider (factor into the regression, but don't change the value), or Ignore (not used in the regression model.). A covariance matrix and residuals are computed for all the non-ignored values. I'm trying to discern the correct terminology is.

Comment: The parameters set as constant values are called constants. The parameters that are found by regression are called parameter values found by the regression of a model fit to data.

Comment: Perhaps you mean nuisance parameter, estimated parameter/ parameter to be estimated, constant, offset etc.?

Answer (score 1):

**Q1 Estimate (solve for)** $\leftarrow$ this terminology in not used. The calculated values of regression coefficients, i.e., parameter-values, are not generally called solutions because generally there are more $y$-values than there are $f(x)$ parameters leading typically to [overdetermined systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system) of equations. Regressions are not solutions per se, but are [approximate solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdetermined_system#Approximate_solutions).

**Q2 Consider (factor into the regression, but don't change the value)** One may call this the *a priori* assignment of parameter values. Sometimes, parameter values of restricted ranges are assigned because of [prior knowledge](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4101693/). Sometimes, a fairly exact **population parameter** is known from prior research, which is then incorporated into a regression model rather than calculating that parameter as a statistic in the sample being analyzed. For example, we might know fairly exactly what the energy of transition is in a nuclear decay, so that may simplify calculating regression spatial frequency of ionizations resulting from interactions of the decay products with the environment.

**Q3 or Ignore (not used in the regression model.)** *Ignore* works, but it may be less confusing to use *not include*. For example, in a cubic fit, the square term may contribute nothing important to the regression, indeed its partial probability may be large, and its inclusion may decrease the adjusted R$^2$-value and/or F-statistic of an [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) regression model.